# How to implement event handling in uiwebview?

Tags: uiwebview, event-handling, ios-simulator, tap

I have taken a webview to show some HTML content in iPhone. Now I want to put some action on user events on the phone. I want to trace the tap event done on the screen by the user on that web view. 
For this I have added a method 
-(void) touchesBegan: (NSSet *) touches withEvent: (UIEvent *) event {
in my code.
But the problem is when I click outside the webview it works perfectly. Bt when I tap on the web view, it does not respond. So, please tell me what should I do to acheive tap event trace on that particular web view.
Help me out.

Answer (score 3):

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)wv shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    NSURL *url = request.URL;
    if ([[url lastPathComponent] isEqual:@"testmessage"]) {
        NSLog(@"Nya");
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

HTML

```
<a href='testmessage'>Test</a>
```

or

```
<script>
 function callObjc(){
  document.location = 'testmessage';
 }
</script>
<a onclick='callObjc();'>Test</a>
```